# Applied function to ImageCollection not working, error: 'Image.constant: Invalid Image.constant type.' Goal is to add a new property to each image

Tags: google-earth-engine

So my end-goal is to add a 'volume' property to each image in my ImageCollection. Below you can see how I tested this for one image, and this works perfectly. The calculation itself is not important at this point but I don't understand why this function doesn't work over the whole image collection but does work for a single image.

PS. my original code is very long, including a classification etc. so instead of adding a link to my code I will just explain as well as I can. Please let me know if there are things that are still unclear.

'classified' is an ImageCollection consisting of 389 images and each image has two bands; a classification band in which only the 'water' class is unmasked and a Digital Surface Model band (called 'DSM')

```
// Extract first image from collection
var img = classified.filterDate('2021-02-11','2021-02-13').first()

// Select digital surface model layer
var dsm = img.select('DSM').clip(geometry5);

// Select water layer in which all but the water class is masked out
var water = img.select('classification');

// Mask out the part of the DSM that is not water
var dsmTotal = dsm.multiply(water)

// Find the maximum value for the DSM
var maxValue = dsmTotal.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: geometry5,
scale: 20});

// This is where I create a layer that contains the same maximum value for all pixels
var maxLayer = ee.Image.constant(maxValue.values(['DSM']))

// The difference (height) between the maximum value and a given pixel
var diff = maxLayer.subtract(dsmTotal)

// Sum to find the total volume of water (pixel size is 20x20)
var volume = diff.multiply(400).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: geometry5, 
    scale: 20,
  }).values();

var img = img.set('volume',volume)
```

So the error I get when I try to apply this to each image in my collection is:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=5):
Image.constant: Invalid Image.constant type.
```

```
var volumeCalc = function(img){
  var dsm = img.select('DSM').clip(geometry5);
  var water = img.select('classification');
  var dsmTotal = dsm.multiply(water)
  var maxValue = dsmTotal.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: geometry5,
    scale: 20});
  var maxLayer = ee.Image.constant(maxValue.values(['DSM']))
  var diff = maxLayer.subtract(dsmTotal)
  var volume = diff.multiply(400).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: geometry5, 
    scale: 20,
  }).values();
  return img.set('volume',volume).copyProperties(img,keepProperties)}

var volumes = classified.map(volumeCalc)
```

I might be overlooking something very obvious but I just can't figure out what is going wrong here. Anyone that can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var maxValue = dsmTotal.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: geometry5,
    scale: 20});
  var maxLayer = ee.Image.constant(maxValue.values(['DSM']))
```

If there are any images in your collection where `dsmTotal` has no unmasked pixels intersecting `geometry5`, then the max reducer will return `null`, and `null` is not a value that can be a pixel value.

That's the problem. Possible solution:

Instead of immediately putting the `maxValue` in a constant image, store it in a property of that image. Then, after the `map()` you can `filter()` out the images that have that property null, before processing the collection further.

Comment: Ah, makes sense! So I now added the property 'max' to the collection and indeed there are instances where the property value is '[null]'. Now trying to filter the collection to remove these:

`var classifiedNonNull = classifiedMax.filter(ee.Filter.neq('max', null));`

Somehow the null is not recognized and no images are filtered out. I tried to add a 0 instead or 'null' or '[null]' but none work. I think this might have something to with how the max property is added. It appears as:
`max: [null] (dropdown menu) 0: nulll`
Any ideas how to refer to this property other than the usual way?

Comment: @jkool You're storing a list containing null; instead, store the value (null or not) directly: `img.set('max', reduceRegion(...).get('DSM'))`. Then use `ee.Filter.notNull('max')` to filter it.